# Need help verifying If I had setup the triple integral that gives the volume of the right circular cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I have the following question which I believe I did it correctly but cannot understand why my professor didn't give me any point for it, yes I have emailed her but am waiting for her response and would like to figure if I am wrong or right.

> 1.) (a) Set up, but do not evaluate, a triple integral that gives the volume of the right circular
> cylinder enclosed by the surfaces $ x^2 + y^2 = 4 $, $z = −10$, and $z = 0$.

> 1.) (b) Set up, but do not evaluate, a triple integral the gives the volume of the right circular cylinder above with a hemisphere sitting atop the cylinder

a.)
$$x^2 + y^2 = 4  \qquad
 z = -10 \qquad
 z=0$$

$$-10 \leq z \leq 0$$
$$0 \leq r \leq 2$$
$$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$

$$ 
V = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \!\! \int_{0}^{2} \!\! \int_{-10}^{0} \!  r \quad dz \, dr \, d\theta
$$

b.)

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9 \qquad
 x^2 + y^2 = 4$$

$$
V = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \!\! \int_{0}^{2} \!\! \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9 - r^2}} r \quad dz \, dr \, d\theta
$$

Comment: @C-RAM Sorry about that, I will update my question with the answer using latex then.

Comment: @C-RAM Okay I have updated my question with my answer using latex

Comment: Part (a) looks fine. For part (b), you're missing the previous lower bound $z=-10$.

Comment: [[1]] Did your teacher ask you to use "$x$ , $y$ , $z$" Cartesian Co-Ordinates ? Was it ok to convert to "$z$ , $\theta$ , $r$" Cylindrical Co-Ordinates ? [[2]] Given the radius of the Cylinder is 2 , then the radius of the Hemisphere is also 2 , not 3. [[3]] We have to add Cylinder Volume to Hemisphere Volume to get the total Volume.